# better approach for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

i need a experts advice that  i should create separate stored procedure for every operation or i should create a single stored procedure for all operation like below example:

```
create proc proc_name
@mode int =0,
@othervariables

as
begin
if @mode =1
begin
insert operation
end

else if @mode =2
begin
update operation
end

else if @mode =3
begin
delete operation
end

else if @mode =4
begin
select statement
end
---- other operations
end
```

Expert i really need your valuable advice. Speed will be main concern for my web site. their will be less insert/update operation and thousands of retrieval operation per minutes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should create separate procedures.

Often you will use different sets of parameters depending on the operation, and it's easier to use and maintain procedures that have only the parameters that they actually use.

You should try to avoid magic numbers like the `mode` parameter in your example. It's much easier to see what's going on with descriptive procedure names than a number in a parameter.

There is no relevant performance gain that you can do by choosing one approach or the other.